# Citation of Base Maps?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

What is the convention for acknowledging the source of the base map used in a map generated in QGIS via the OpenLayers plug-in?

I'm a teacher of high school geography students who use QGIS to generate maps from data collected in the field, and their work is submitted to an external organisation for assessment, so academic honesty is especially important.

Students are entering data into .csv files and creating their own shapefiles, which I'm fine with... but they're putting that data over a base map - usually one of the OSM maps available via the OpenLayers plugin (QGIS 2.14). I currently have them simply put 'Base map: [base map name]' within their map info to at least acknowledge the source. See example below:

[image: sample map]

Comment: Basemaps obtained through the quickmapservices plugin have the copyright information saved as a layer property, which makes them easy to site. I'm not sure if  OpenLayers basemaps have the same. Since you're mapping in China, you might find this question helpful: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/313878/81764

Comment: This question may also be helpful [Map material from china not allowed to leave the country](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/320871/81764).

Comment: If it's OSM, see [this page](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Researcher_Information#Citation_requirements).

Comment: @csk thank you for the links. The students' work is only viewed by an examiner for the International Baccalaureate and not published anywhere else, I think we're safe from the PSB. As a side note, I switched from using GPS to mobile phones for collecting location data because of the restrictions on foreigners using GPS devices.

Comment: Given the offset built into standard basemaps within the borders of China, is there any difficulty getting the data the students collect to line up with the basemaps? Or do cellphones automatically offset the data in the same way?

Comment: @csk it depends on the app some do, some don't. Coordinate data is coordinate data, so making sure the CRS is common between the app and the QGIS project is helpful. We set a reference point at the start of data collection at a road intersection and students move data points in QGIS en masse to align to the reference point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two methods for attributing maps. One is quick and easy; the other is less convenient but better practice.

**Method One (Quick and Dirty): Use Basemaps "With Attribution"**

This is the method you're currently using. I often use this method, as it's quick and easy. You basically just add the name of the basemap layer to the final map.

Layers obtained through the QuickMapServices plugin come with Attribution metadata, but it doesn't look like OpenLayers basemaps have any Attribution metadata. Here's what the Attribution metadata looks like for the "Google Hybrid" layer obtained through the QuickMapServices plugin:

[image]

So a quick and easy way to attribute this basemap is with this attribution text: "Basemap: Google Hybrid, Map data ©2015 Google"

or "Basemap: Google Hybrid (obtained through QuickMapServices QGIS plugin), Map data ©2015 Google"

The problem with this method, is that each basemap provider has their own terms of service and copyright restriction. If you don't read the terms of service for that data provider, you might be unknowingly violating them. For example, some providers may allow you to use their basemaps, with attribution, for any purpose. Another provider may allow you to use them for non-commercial purposes only. A third provider might allow you to use them for non-commercial purposes for free, and for commercial purposes only if you pay a fee. To make sure you're not violating copyright, you should follow Method Two (below).

**Pro: Quick and easy.**

**Con: You *might* be violating copyrights.**

---

**Method Two (Best Practice): Follow the Terms of Service for the Specific Data Provider**

Each basemap provider (Google, OSM/Stamen, Bing, Apple Maps, Wikimedia Maps, etc) has their own terms of service. The best/safest method is to read the *current* terms of service for the data provider of the basemap you're using. Notice in the image above that underneath the map Title, is a web address for Google's attribution guide. If you go to this page, you'll find rules about what Google does and doesn't allow you to do with their basemaps.

Most basemaps from the QuickMapServices plugin have this link included in their metadata. OpenLayers doesn't provide this link, so you'll have to locate it yourself on the website for the data provider.

**Pro: You know you're not violating copyrights.**

**Con: Takes longer.**

---

*My recommendation:*

Assign each of your students to research the copyright requirements of *one* basemap provider. Have them write a short summary of those requirements. Provide all the summaries to the class. Then require your students to follow the copyright requirements when they produce their maps.

You might be tempted to ignore copyrights and terms of service, because it's "only a school assignment," so you figure you'll probably get away with it. But I think you would do a disservice to your students if you did this. Instead, take this opportunity to teach your students to do it right.